# The following errors occurred while importing projects. Some projects may not be loaded

Tags: java, eclipse, import

The image shows what error comes while importing a team file .psf and I am totally new to eclipse so don't know how it works

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your import path. Looks like whatever file you are trying to open is not in that path.
You can get the existing path from  `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`

Comment: I am importing a new team file and it shows this error